# Error while Converting Presto SQL to Hive format

Tags: sql, hive, presto

I have a presto query that I am trying to convert to Hive format. When I try to convert, am getting compilation error.

**Presto query:**

```
select 
 id
, json_extract_scalar(item, '$.ticker') as ticker
, json_extract_scalar(item, '$.name') as name
FROM stock_table,
unnest(cast(json_parse(items) as array(json))) as t(item);
```

**Stock Table data:**

| ID | Items |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | [{"ticker":"TSLA","name":"TESLA"}, {"ticker":"SQ","name":"BLOCK"}] |
| 11 | [{"ticker":"AAPL","name":"APPLE"}] |

**Stock table definition:**

| column | data type |
| --- | --- |
| id | bigint |
| items | varchar |

**Expected output:**

| ID | ticker | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | TSLA | TESLA |
| 10 | SQ | BLOCK |
| 11 | AAPL | APPLE |

Hive query that I used:

```
select id
, get_json_object(items, '$.ticker') as ticker
, get_json_object(items, '$.name') as name
FROM stock_table
lateral view explode(json_tuple(items)) t as item;
```

**Error:**

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10081]: UDTF's are not supported outside the SELECT clause, nor nested in expressions
```

Please advise how I can convert the given query to Hive supported query.

Comment: remove `explode`

Comment: ```Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 4:12 cannot recognize input near 'lateral' 'view' '(' in lateral view``` Failed with this error